# Take/Make A Run/Walk

Tags: word-choice, phrasal-verbs

Suppose the context is a guy going to a store to buy something:

> 1. He ***made a run*** to the store.
> 2. He ***took a run*** to the store.
> 3. He ***made a walk*** to the store.
> 4. He ***took a walk*** to the store.

"*Take a walk*" is definitely standard English.  But, is there anything wrong with the "*take a run*", "*make a run*", and "*make a walk*" patterns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the *patterns* of "take a run", "make a run", and "make a walk", but each specific phrase may or may not have precedents that describe going to the store. Specifically:

> He **made a run** to the store. [This is the normal way to say it!]
>
> He **took a run** to the store. [This sounds strange. Usually "take a run" means to run for exercise, not to perform a chore.]
>
> He **made a walk** to the store. [This sounds very strange. There is no precedent for "make a walk" to mean walking. So, when you combine "make" and "walk", the listener is forced to think that "walk" means something like a concrete sidewalk, which you could make. If you say "make a walk to the store", your meaning is clear, but it sounds foreign.]
>
> He **took a walk** to the store. [This sounds strange in the same way that "take a run to the store" sounds strange. Normally, if you "take a walk", you are walking for exercise or you are quitting something abruptly. You might "take a walk around the block", but there's little precedent for "take a walk to the store".]

There is no grammatical rule for any of this. You just have to learn from experience how new phrases echo familiar phrases. Some more information about how phrases play a role in English comparable to individual words is [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/57392/6700) and [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/59247/6700).

---

By the way, a well-known precedent for "take a walk" occurs in [this song](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%22take+a+walk+on+the+wild+side%22+song&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gws_rd=ssl).

Answer (score 3):

*To make a run* usually means to travel to a nearby location, buy something or perform an errand, then typically return."  It implies it's done rather quickly - typically for the purpose of getting one or a few items that are needed right away (it's a *run* so it's supposed to be quick).

E.g. you might make a run to pick up some soda for a party starting in an hour (and might even call that a *soda run*), but you wouldn't make a run to do your monthly shopping with your mother-in-law.  That's more of a *trip* - though "make a trip" can be used to describe the same things as "make a run."

Anyway, unless you want to come off as being sarcastic, this doesn't work with *walk*.  *Make a walk* is not a well-known expression - a *walk* is not something that's *made* when it is performed.

*Take a walk* does mean to go walking leisurely for a time, and *take a walk to X* does mean to walk to X, often implying that its for leisure.  When you make a run, you are NOT travelling for leisure (your purpose is to get something and  come back), you are travelling for a well-defined purpose, so *take a run* does not work to express the same thing.

---

Now, *take* and *make* are "low-level" English words that can be used to express many things, albeit without precision.  *Make* can often mean something similar *to perform*, *to bring about*, or *to manifest* and *take* can often mean something similar *to consume*.

So there may be situations where a speaker might be compelled to say *take a run* - if the "run" is something that can be "consumed".  E.g. - let's say the speaker is at an event where there are limited opportunities to run - "taking a run" would be appropriate to say there - "Hey, you can go take your run now" or "Hurry up and take your run before you lose your spot."

And there is also situations where the act of walking could be performing - it would not be out of place for a fashion model's boss or manager to say "It's time to make your walk now" to tell them to stroll down the catwalk.

But *make a run* and *take a walk* are well-known phrases and you can't switch *run* and *walk* between them without sounding awkward to a native speaker.

Comment: Good. But you might want to explain that making a run does not typically involve actual running. _Making a run_ (or _going _on a run_ ) are completely separate idioms from going _for a run_. (And then there's "take a run AT IT", something altogether different.)

Comment: Yep ... now that I think of it, there's also *make a run for it* which means to quickly get away from something ...